# BackgroundWorker RunWorkerAsync appears to not trigger

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I have this code

```
class Program
{
    private static void test(int i)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        int i = 5;
        worker.DoWork += (obj, ev) => test(i);            
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

When I run it, nothing is printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your application terminates before `test` gets called. In any case you *don't* need to use the deprecated BGW class to run work in the background, especially in console applications. Use `await Task.Run(...)`

Comment: The Main() method in a console app is special.  When it ends then the main thread of the app ends as well and the CLR has a good reason to terminate the process.  Only another thread with its IsBackground property set to *true* can avoid that.  You don't have one.  Essential insight is that the main thread is not doing anything useful other than quitting.  So it might as well do the DoWork code.

Comment: Check this if it helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846718/how-to-wait-for-background-worker-to-finish-processing

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the problem was the application exiting before the worker could run.

Answer (score 0):

As per @PanagiotisKanavos's advice, you should utilize `await Task.Run` below:

```
async void SomeMethod()
{
    int i = 5;
    await Task.Run(() => test(i));
}
```